# Remove Selected Element of MultiSelect Widget Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu

I am using [MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) This is very good plug in.

Anybody tell me how can i remove a selected element from this widget.

I am using this code `removeBtn` is my button .

```
$("#removeBtn").click(function() {
    var el = $("select").multiselect("getChecked");
    alert(el);
    el.removeAttr('selected');
    el.multiselect('refresh');
    alert("Completed");
});
```

I need to make a code when `removebutton` is clicked the selected option will be removed.. But this is not working..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a checkbox shouldn't that be:

```
el.removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: ya thanks for your reply  but this is not working for this widget.

Comment: Finally i got the solution. for removing a element first i will get all the elements from this and then remove that from an array after that i will use this  el.empty(); to empty and will add the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, and at the end I found solution...
You can open jquery.multiselect.js file and you will find there a event "uncheckAll". This event is called when you click on header option Uncheck All, so you can use that event to deselect your selected options. This is it:

```
$("#removeBtn").click(function() {
    $("select").multiselect("uncheckAll");
    $("select").multiselect('refresh');
});
```